# Soundmanager 2 and iOS using from and to commands

Tags: javascript, ios, soundmanager2

This code is working on MacOs and not on iOS.

```
soundManager.setup({url:'soundmanager2/',onready:function(){var mySound=soundManager.createSound({id:'aSound',url:'soundmanager2/notes.mp3'});mySound.play({from:50000,to:52000});},ontimeout:function(){}});}
```

When I do not use the 'from' and 'to' commands it works fine on iOS... but I need audio sprite.

Any idea to fix that or another way to make audio sprite working with iOS ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be using something like [Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js) for audio sprites that work on mobile devices.

SoundManager uses HTML5 audio and a Flash fallback. You need to be using the Web Audio API for sound sprites on mobile (which Howler.js supports).